# Can "Why don't you be" be correct? If so, how is it different from "Why aren't you"?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs

In [this comic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whS5y.jpg) occurs the phrase:

> *Why don't you be more social?*

This sounds wrong to me, but I'm not sure why.  Can the phrase *Why don't you be...* be correct?  If it is correct, how does the meaning differ from *Why aren't you ...?*

Googling lists lyrics of some songs, but I do not dare take that as a reference for grammatical correctness.

Comment: Can you explain *why* you think there might be something wrong with this construction? Are you happy with *"I want to be more social"*, and *"Why don't you relax?"*, for example? FWIW I myself am perfectly happy with both of those, and don't see anything significantly different in your example.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not sure, it just sounds wrong to me.  I've edited the question.

Comment: I think maybe it's just that you wouldn't hear it very often, because in practice people would be much more likely to say *"Why **can't** you be more sociable?"*. (Well, ***I*** think they'd use *sociable* rather than *social*, but that's a personal opinion.) But the *don't/won't/can't* choice is just a matter of idiomatic preference - nothing to do with "grammatical correctness" as such.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> NOTE: Like FumbleFingers, I'm more comfortable with *sociable* here, so I'm going to use that instead, but it makes no difference at all to what I'm saying. If you're interested, the matter has been discussed on [**ELU**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95277/unsociable-vs-unsocial-in-the-following-sentence/95319#95319).

These two questions reflect somewhat different meanings of *BE* when used of persons.

When we say of someone that *he **is** sociable* (or *gracious* or *funny* or *a complete jerk*) we are speaking about their *character*, who they are.

But when we say of someone that *he **is being** sociable* we are speaking about their *behavior*, how they are for the time being acting.

Similarly, when you ask someone "Why aren't you more sociable?", with the simple-present verb, you are asking about the simple-present version: "What is the cause of your unsociable character?"

But when you ask "Why can't you (*or* won't you *or* don't you—*they amount to pretty much the same thing*) **be** more social" you aren't really asking a question, you are challenging their behavior: "You really ought to behave more sociably, and I can't understand why you don't."

Comment: It's like ser vs. estar in Spanish.

Answer (score 1):

"Why don't you be more sociable?" can be correct, if it refers to **one**, particular, occasion.

"Why aren't you more sociable?" would be correct if it is meant **generally**.